# Slow website loading with avada on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, performance, web

Hi i am new to using this stackoverflow, and could do we some help. My website seems to take a while to load up and is not as quick as id like. Im using the avada theme on wordpress and a few widgets that are needed. Ive tried getting it the best i can but if anyone thinks they can see what is causing it, It would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
keith

[www.seamlessgutteringcompany.co.uk](http://www.seamlessgutteringcompany.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

Your website speed load is quite good , 1.2s load time . Just maybe you can make it a little bit faster by adding ...

```
Header set Connection keep-alive
```

to your htaccess file ..

But I'd leave it as it is .

Reference : 
https://varvy.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that but it never seems to work.